# Form over several pages - URL should remain

Tags: php, forms, url

Don´t know if  my  english is sufficient  to explain this right:
I have  made  a Form that is needs 4 or  5 pages until  final  submit  comes.
On every change the Post is added  to the new  page as a  hidden field and  a new  script  is called.

```
<form method="post" action="form4.php">
```

My problem is i dont  want  the browser  to  show  the  url to  the new script  and ideally keep it at the origin url.

I dont  know the  right terms to search on google  or here  for a  solution. Maybe  you  can give me a   hint how  to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think i found   another  solution  and  want  to share  it:

the solution with  the  switch and  the solution with  ajax  made  me  think about  how  to solve  this easier. why not make  the form on one  page and hide the different parts. what waas before  a button to submit the part  is now  a button to hide previous part and  show next.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function() 
            {
            $$('.blau').set('text', 'Erkennen Sie die Heilpflanze?');
            $('page_2').slide('hide');
            $('page_3').slide('hide');
            $('page_4').slide('hide');
            $('page_5').slide('hide');
            var togglePrefix = 'toggle_', boxPrefix = 'page_', emptyPrefix = '';
            $$('.submit_box a').addEvent('click', function(e)
                {
                e.stop();
                var id = $(this.get('id').replace(togglePrefix,emptyPrefix));
                var id_new = parseInt($(this).get('id').replace(togglePrefix, emptyPrefix)) + 1; 
                var next = ('page_'+id_new);
                var id_old = $(this.get('id').replace(togglePrefix,boxPrefix));
                $(id_old).set('slide', {duration: 'long', transition: 'linear'});
                $(id_old).slide('out');
                $(next).slide('in');

                if (next == 'page_1')
                  {

                  }
                if (next == 'page_2')
                  {

                  }
                if (next == 'page_3')
                  {

                  }
                if (next == 'page_4')
                  {
                  $$('.blau').set('text', '....und die letzte ist?');
                  }
                if (next == 'page_5')
                  {
                  $$('.blau').set('text', 'Nur noch ein paar Daten:');
                  }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

the html:

```
<form id="gewinnspiel" name="gewinnspiel" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>">
<div id="page_1"> 
    <div class="inhalt-gewinn">
      <div class="gewinn_bild"></div>
      <div class="gewinn_form">
              <div class="input_box">
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Kamille" /><span>Kamille</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Kaktus" /><span>Kaktus</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Krokus" /><span>Krokus</span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="submit_box"><a id="toggle_1" class="frage">nächste Frage...</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gewinn_werbung"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page_2">
    <div class="inhalt-gewinn">
      <div class="gewinn_bild"></div>
      <div class="gewinn_form">
          <div class="input_box">
              <div><input type="radio" name="frage2" value="Ringelblume" /><span>Ringelblume</span></div>
              <div><input type="radio" name="frage2" value="Rotklee" /><span>Rotklee</span></div>
              <div><input type="radio" name="frage2" value="Ringelkraut" /><span>Ringelkraut</span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="submit_box"><a id="toggle_2" class="frage">nächste Frage...</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gewinn_werbung"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page_3">
    <div class="inhalt-gewinn">
      <div class="gewinn_bild"></div>
      <div class="gewinn_form">
          <div class="input_box">
                <div><input type="radio" name="frage3" value="Enzian" /><span>Enzian</span></div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="frage3" value="Eisenkraut" /><span>Eisenkraut</span></div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="frage3" value="Eiche" /><span>Eiche</span></div>  
              </div>
              <div class="submit_box"><a id="toggle_3" class="frage">nächste Frage...</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gewinn_werbung"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page_4">
    <div class="inhalt-gewinn">
        <div class="gewinn_bild"></div>
        <div class="gewinn_form">
            <div class="input_box">
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage4" value="Wollblume" /><span>Wollblume</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage4" value="Tulpe" /><span>Tulpe</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage4" value="Rose" /><span>Rose</span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="submit_box"><a id="toggle_4" class="frage">nächste Frage...</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gewinn_werbung"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page_5">
    <div class="inhalt-gewinn">
        <div class="gewinn_bild"></div>
        <div class="gewinn_form">
            <div class="input_box_ende">     
                <?php echo '<input name="date" type="hidden" value="', time(), '" />'; ?>
                <div class="nosee">eMail:<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?=$_POST['email']; ?>" size="30" /></div>
                <div><span>Vorname:</span><input type="text" name="vorname" value="<?=$_POST['vorname']; ?>"/></div>
                <div><span>Nachname:</span><input type="text" name="nachname" value="<?=$_POST['nachname']; ?>"/></div>
                <div><span>Strasse:</span><input type="text" name="strasse" value="<?=$_POST['strasse']; ?>"/></div>
                <div><span>Ort:</span><input type="text" name="ort" value="<?=$_POST['ort']; ?>"/></div>
                <div><span>PLZ:</span><input type="text" name="plz" value="<?=$_POST['plz']; ?>"/></div>
                <div><span>eMail:</span><input type="text" name="imehl" value="<?=$_POST['imehl']; ?>"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit_box"><input id="submit" name="senden" type="submit" value="Senden" /></div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

all working !   thx for the inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to handle the form by the same script in stages.

```
<form action="formhandler.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_stage" value="1" />
....
</form>
```

and within the formhandler.php:

```
switch($_POST['form_stage']) {
   case 5:
       // handle the stage 5 stuff here
       break;
   case 4:
       // handle stage 4 stuff here, output form for stage 5
       break;
   case 3:
       // handle stage 3 stuff here, output form for stage 4
       break;
   case 2:
      // ditto
      break;
   case 1:
   default:
      // display initial form here
}
```

Of course, you don't have to use a switch for this. A long sequence of if/else if works just as well, it comes down to personal preference/code complexity. But this basic workflow allows you to keep the same url and still display multiple different forms without having to resort to AJAX/javascript.

Comment: 2 Questions  to this  suggestion:

1st: i guess  i have  to write  new form_stage value on submit  to hidden field??
2nd: so far  i stored results of previous  pages  in hidden fields. this method  i´m not sure  how  i  can accomplish here...    i dont  want  to  go the  way  with sessions.

Comment: @Arweb It's best you store the data in a session. To allow the user to have several forms open at the same time, you can pass a conversation id, just like you pass the page.

Comment: Storing the intermediate data in the session is an option, but you have to be careful that if a user starts filling out two copies of the form, that the two different copies don't stomp on each other. If you need to guard against that, you'll have to take special steps in the session AND form to identify which copy of the data goes where, or store everything in hidden fields as the user progresses through.

Answer (score 0):

If the action of the form is form4.php, then you can't change which URL the form posts to.  However, you can do a redirect immediately after processing the data of the post to the URL you want the user to be at.

Alternately, you can change your form actions so they all post to the same page and just allow for multiple types of posting in your PHP.

Comment: when i  go  to 2nd  site  of  form  i store  results of  first  site  in hidden  fields.    if i do a  redirect i guess  my  hidden fields  are lost?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax and pass data from form to php script and than load new form. Or you can pass argument(hidden or not) to file:

```
<form action="form.php?p=1" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Hidden parameter:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="p">
...
</form>
```

Depending on p value you load proper form and do things with rest of data.

Comment: a very elegant  solution  but so far i used  ajax  only  to display some  extra content in some div container  but not  to alter  a form...  but  thx  for  the  suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Load your php site inside an `iframe` within some page.. The url of this page will always remain.

Comment: this  sounds  the  most practical solution  to  me  but as  i never have  worked  with iframes i have an gordian knot in my  head....
i guess  the  first page of the  form has  to be  in  the  iframe and if i  change to next  page it loads inside without changing url?